# How to fix error code: 0xc0000225

Tags: windows-10

I installed another windows 10 on my PC. With the previous Windows 10 already installed, during startup it showed a menu for me to select the windows 10 I want to boot in. After some time I decided to delete the new installed windows 10 by just deleting its partition(where it was installed) by using Ubuntu disks app. Now the previously installed windows stopped working and shows me a blue screen with "Recovery" written on top.

It also showed some options but none of them worked.
Can someone please help me?
Also automatic repair doesn't work for me.

Comment: On the recovery screen have you tried troubleshoot -> advanced -> startup repair?

Comment: Thanks for giving a suggestion, I will definitely try that!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author has resolved their problem themselves

Comment: no please do not remove it, it can be helpful to others

Comment: How can this help others, I see no solution?